# How to change color of an item in my ComboBoxList

Tags: c#, combobox, comboboxlist

I have a `ComboBoxList` which has certain items and a button beneath it. On click event, I want to **change Text Color** of item if that was checked (changed text color to Red or Green). But if item color has already changed (to red or green) and item has un-checked in second round, then color should revert to original.
Following is the code snippet  that I tried.

**ASPX**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1"
          runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:checkboxlist runat="server"
                              EnableViewState="true"
                              id="cbl" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1"
                        runat="server"
                        Text="Button"
                        OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**ServerSide**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for ( int i =0; i< count; i++)
    {
        if (this.ColumnsList.Items(i).Selected)
        {
            this.ColumnsList.Items(i).Attributes.Add("style", "Color=Red;");
        }
    }
}
```

Error message is

> Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.Items'
>   cannot be used like a method.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `ForEach` instead of `For` and try below code.

```
foreach (ListItem item in this.ColumnsList.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        item.Attributes.Add("style", "Color: Red");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

```
    if (this.ColumnsList.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        this.ColumnsList.Items[i].Attributes.Add("style", "color: red;");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this... It is working fine on test..

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work for this use case.. As this will work only for first three items.. what about rest.. This is incomplete answer..

Comment: Oh!... it's just an example... I think you can solve the for loop boolean value... This is your complete answer...I have corrected the answer..Please have a look... :)

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in your code.

1. Instead of using `RoundBracket ()` use a `SquareBraket []`. `()` doesn't work well in this context.

**Example** Use `CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected` in place of `CheckBoxList1.Items(I).Selected`

2. Instead of using `Add("style", "Color=Red;");` to add color, use `Add("style", "Color: Red");`